# Can Rikudou Madara activate his Limbo Perfect Susanoo in the anime after Mugen Tsukuyomi ends?

Tags: naruto

Rikudou Madara in "Naruto Shippuden: Ultimate Ninja Storm 4" activates his Limbo Perfect Susanoo, and  uses it against Naruto and Sasuke.

Can he activate Limbo Perfect Susanoo in the anime? I think it is amazing  to  see final battle with Madara before his death.

[image]

Comment: I would tell you, but Explaining  it would RUIN the next Canon scene, but lets just say Madara has little fight left in him.

Comment: maybe 2 or  3  episodes of  fighting  against  madara  before  his death  is  enough  to  be  very  cool

Comment: yes, it could be quite cool and and it would be nice to see his full power, but we will never know outside of Filler. He definitely does not die until the end of the war itself, but he does not do much for showing off his power now. the Meteor shower is the biggest show of power he does. There are only 2 battles left, but one to end the war.

Comment: If you kept up with the anime, I believe you now have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

He never does, but he theoretically could. He's still an Uchiha, and still has the Rinnegan and also uses Limbo while in Six Paths mode, however there is no reason for him to. The Truth Seeking Balls are a more perfect defense than Susano'o and the new abilities granted to him by the Six Paths' chakra seemed to be at least as powerful, if not moreso, than his Susano'o.

Comment: but  madara  didn’t  show  its  full power  as  a six paths madara .  he appeared  in the manga  weaker  than obito  and  splitted  easily  by  sasuke’s  sowrd .  I  think  it is necessary  to  show  full  power  of  madara  before  his  death ,  it  will be  very  cool .

Comment: @fulleriteman TBH, there is no reason why he has to show off his full power. Certainly we feel an obligation for him to do so, but no writer is ever forced to show off everything.

Comment: We all know that they couldn't have shown Madara's full power. Even without that, he was a highly op character so much so that they had to rush in a character like Kaguya.